# Cannot find Ensime plugin for Gradle

Tags: ensime

I've read this http://ensime.org/build_tools/gradle/ but the instructions here are wrong: `ensime-gradle` simply doesn't exist in `jcenter` repository.  There is a different version of `ensime-gradle` in https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/ but `ensime-mode` complains that this plugin is no longer supported:

```
You are using a .ensime file format that is no longer supported.
You must upgrade your build tool or downgrade to ensime stable.
See http://ensime.org/editors/emacs/install
```

Unfortunately, I have to use Gradle for this project.  So, I cannot replace it by `sbt`.  Does anyone know where I can find the `ensime-gradle` plugin of the version that does work with the resent `ensime-mode`?

---

Further examination showed that `.ensime` file doesn't have any values for `:ensime-server-jars` and `:ensime-server-version`. I'm trying to understand why aren't they being generated...

Comment: Whoever dowvoted, care to comment? I don't care about karma points: I really want to see someone who got this to work, or at least knows something about this problem.

Comment: not sure why you were downvoted - the plugin is still dead

Answer (score 2):

OK, after more searching and swapping dependencies, I found this ticket: https://github.com/ensime/ensime-gradle/issues/60 . Conclusion: Ensime plugin for Gradle simply doesn't work, there are no versions of Ensime and Gradle Ensime plugin that are compatible and the work on the plugin must have stopped about two years ago.